# Creating group rights in Azure for SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm probably not phrasing that correctly. I have been asked to find a way to create a group in Azure; grant that group dbreader and dbwriter rights to SQL server, then create users in that group and assign non-Azure applications to those users. I am sure I'm not phrasing some of this correctly. The idea is that applications in the field should have access to the Azure-based Sql Server but only reading and writing to the DB.

RON

Answer (score 0):

from your question it is not very clear if you are asking about SQL Server on the plain VM or SQL Server as a service (SQL Azure). If SQL Server on the VM, then it should be the same as locally.
If SQL Azure, you can try to add your user to the db_dbdatareader/writer role using Visual Studio or SSMS.

[image]

Or use the SQL syntax, something like this one:

```
CREATE ROLE MyDatabaseReaderRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

GRANT 
  ALTER, 
  CONTROL, 
  DELETE, 
  EXECUTE, 
  INSERT, 
  REFERENCES, 
  SELECT, 
  TAKE OWNERSHIP, 
  UPDATE, 
  VIEW DEFINITION 
ON SCHEMA::dbo
  TO MyDatabaseReaderRole
GO

-- Add an existing user to the new role created 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'MyDatabaseReaderRole', 'SomeUser'
GO
```